# What is the space complexity of this code?

Tags: c, algorithm

```
int f(int n)
{ 
    if (n <= 1)
    { 
         return 1;
    } 
    return f(n - 1) + f(n - 1);
}
```

I know that the time complexity is `O(2^n)` and I understand why.

But I don't understand why the space complexity is `O(n)`.
I was told that it's because at any given time there are only `n` nodes, but it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Write the formula and solve it. `Memory(n) = 1 + max(Memory(n-1), Memory(n-1))`

Comment: This question is a better fit for http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because the second `f(n-1)` can't run until the first one completes (or vice versa -- it's the same either way). The first call will recurse `n` times, then all those will return, so that will push a total of `n` stack frames. Then the second call will do the same thing.

So it never gets more than `n` levels deep in the recursion, and that's the only contributor to space complexity.

Comment: But how do you know that this is how the operating system implements recursion? potentially it can execute each call with threads, each one waits for other two... I just don't understand why in the worst case it can be more than O(n). As I see it in the general case it can be O(n)

Comment: Complexity calculations are theoretical, not based on a specific implementation, and this conceptually only needs a single thread, with sequential recursive calls. If you rewrite the code using actual threads, then the complexity will be different.

Comment: but this is my point. since it's not based on specific implementation you have to consider the worst case scenario. isn't it?

Comment: Not necessarily, you only have to consider what's necessary, not some arbitrarily bad way of implementing it. There are also some simplifying assumptions, such as all numbers taking the same amount of space (if you use Peano numbers, each number takes O(n) space).

Comment: @chris the OS is not involved anyway, it can't be sneaky and implement calls with threads because it has no say over how *you* implement calls - and it's you doing it, you're just using a compiler to do it for you here, but you could have written the machine code by hand. If you change the hypothetical situation to "the compiler might decide to waste arbitrary amounts of space", then you have created a hypothetical world about which nothing interesting can be said, so it's not useful.

Comment: @chris the OS knows that running two threads will potentially increase memory complexity and, if it's a good OS, will only do so if enough memory is available. Anyway, if we multi-thread with a constant amount of threads, memory complexity is still O(k*n)=O(n)

Comment: This is a classic example of a time-space tradeoff. Using threads can reduce the time taken if there are enough processors (although not the time complexity, because complexity can't take physical limits into account), at the cost of all the space used to hold the intermediate results.

Comment: @chris Q: What if the computer decides to guess an answer, then run your program to see if its guess was right, then repeat until it guesses right? A: It's irrelevant, computers don't do that.

Comment: @chris: none of the popular C compilers ever creates a thread implicitly. You either need to create threads manually, or use a library that allows you to annotate the source code when parallelization needs to happen like with OpenMP.

Answer (score 7):

Space complexity is O(n) because one side of recursion, reaches the leaves, and returns up, until the root, similar happens for the other side of recursion and in every middle step, the space used in the recursion cannot be bigger than O of depth of recursion tree.

Answer (score 5):

Draw the exponential time complexity tree and the length of path of any leaf from the root of the tree will be linear. **This linear path is the space complexity of the algorithm**. The algorithm will traverse each of those paths to solve the problem but at any point the maximum number of recursive calls stored in the stack will be linear. Ex: for `f(3)`

```
         3 
       /   \ 
     2      2 
    / \    / \ 
   1   1  1   1
```

The maximum length from root to leaf is `O(n)`. Thus, the space complexity is also `O(n)`.

Comment: Why do you have different values in the left and right subtrees? They're both called with `n-1` as the parameter. Maybe you thought he was calculating Fibonacci?